# Average when meeting where clause

Tags: sql

I want to find the average amount of a field where it meets a criterion. It is embedded in a big table but I would like this average field in there instead of doing it in a separate table.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select....
Avg( (currbal) where (select * from table 
                       where ament2 in ('r1','r2'))
From table
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Select Avg(currbal) FROM table where ament2 in ('r1','r2')`?

Comment: Because its in a table with other sums which don't want this where criteria so it needs to be embedded into the avg statement

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more of what those dots represent.  One issue is 'which group of rows is the average meant to be averaging'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to AVG only a subset of a query use `case when ... then` to replace value in non-matching rows with null as nulls are ignored by avg().

```
Select id,
       sum(something) SomethingSummed,
       avg(case when ament2 in ('r1','r2') then currbal end) CurrbalAveragedForR1R2
  From [table]
 group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the other sums which you want to be embedded into the `AVG` statement, inside the table reference inside the `FROM` clause. Something like:

```
SELECT AVG(currbal)
FROM
(
    SELECT * -- other sums
    FROM table
    WHERE ament2 IN ('r1','r2')
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a full sub-select into the select list:

```
SELECT ...,
       (SELECT AVG(Currbal) FROM Table WHERE ament2 IN ('r1', 'r2')) AS avg_currbal,
       ...
  FROM ...
```

Whether that will do exactly what you want depends on a number of things.  You might need to make that into a correlated subquery; assuming 'ament2' is in Table, it is not a correlated sub-query at the moment.

Comment: I imagine this won't work when the base query has WHERE clauses, unless you intend to take the clause into the subquery as well.

Comment: It will 'work' in the sense of producing an answer.  Whether it produces the required answer depends on what the required answer is.  As written, assuming that `ament2` is a column in Table, it produces the same answer in every row of output and is evaluated once; the value is the grand average of the current balances (Currbal) where `ament2 IN ('r1', 'r2')`.  This probably isn't what is required — hence my mention of correlated sub-queries, etc.  I don't think we have enough information from the question to divine what is really wanted, yet.  Either that or I've not yet had enough coffee.